# How to change tktimepicker default clock type from 12-hours to 24-hours?

Tags: python, tkinter, clock

The tktimepicker default clock type is 12 hours. How do I change tktimepicker clock type from 12-hours to 24-hours?

Comment: The widget has design fault that even you have chosen 24-hours format, the `AM/PM` selector is still shown.  Also `24` should be shown as `0` in the analog clock and the hour spinbox.

Comment: The above issue stated by acw has now been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkTimePicker/blob/master/Documentation.md), there are two ways:

1. Pass an argument `type=constants.HOURS24` to the constructor of your class.
2. use the `configure_24HrsTime` method on `SpinTimePickerModern` and `SpinTimePickerOld` objects.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkTimePicker) if you need to refer to it.